# Pitch detection (TarsosDSP) doesn't work after going from activity to mainactivity and back to activity again

Tags: android, android-activity, refresh, pitch

So I have a main activity where I can choose between other activities.

On one activity there is real time pitch detection via TarsosDSP going on and it works when I start that activity for the first time. However, when I go back to the main activity via the android back button and then start the pitch detection activity again, the detection doesn't start.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_1);
    note1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.note1);
    note2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.note2);
    note3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.note3);
    note4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.note4);
    note5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.note5);
    pitchText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pitchText);
    noteText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.noteText);
    mic();
    random();
}
```

...and the pitch detection

```
public void mic()
{

    AudioDispatcher dispatcher = AudioDispatcherFactory.fromDefaultMicrophone(22050,1024,0);

    PitchDetectionHandler pdh = new PitchDetectionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handlePitch(PitchDetectionResult res, AudioEvent e) {
            final float pitchInHz = res.getPitch();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    processPitch(pitchInHz);
                }
            });
        }
    };
    AudioProcessor pitchProcessor = new PitchProcessor(PitchProcessor.PitchEstimationAlgorithm.FFT_YIN, 22050, 1024, pdh);
    dispatcher.addAudioProcessor(pitchProcessor);
    Thread audioThread = new Thread(dispatcher, "Audio Thread");
    audioThread.start();

}
public void processPitch(float pitchInHz) {

    //there are several ifs and else ifs but would make the question too long
}
```

Comment: You have to be sure about Activity life cycles before try to solve your issue. Are "onPause()", "onStop()" and "onDestroy()" called from the SecondaryActivity when you return back? Does your code stop the PitchDetector when the SecondaryActivity is destroyed? An Activity could be Destroyed by a BACK button, but could be only Paused using HOME button or just Resumed without the "OnCreate()" event if re-opened via RECENT button. So I think you should do more tests or we cannot help you very much without more informations about it.

Comment: But since I press the back button the secondary activity should be destroyed, right? And once I open it from the main activity again, everything should start up again, like in the first start, or am I wrong?

Comment: It depends of many things and how you're developing Activities. However does your PitchDetectorActivity executes something like "PitchDetector.stop()" when it is Destroyed? Because I start to think that the Thread remains active when you press the BACK button and you cannot start another PitchDetector while the first one is still in use.

Comment: No, can I interrupt the thread when I press the back button somehow?

Comment: I never used TarsosDSP but seems that "AudioDispatcher" has a "stop()" method